Воспроизводится ошибка 404 при нескольких автомиграциях, где ошибка? gin
package db

import (
    "awesomeGin/models"
    "log"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func Init(url string) *gorm.DB {
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(url), &gorm.Config{})
    DisableForeignKeyConstraintWhenMigrating: true ,
    
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Book{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Game{})
    return db
}


404 это ошибка HTTP сервера, при чем здесь миграции?
